# How to loop over glm testing different models

Tags: r, for-loop, glm

I have a vector `a` which contains some combinations of my variables. In order to get the best possible model (smallest BIC), I hoped to be able to loop over the `glm` function - well, that didn't work.

The data looks something like this:

```
de.dat <- data.frame(death=c(0,0,0,1,0), ac=c(1, 2, 2, 3, 2), fv=c(1,0,0,0,1), vs=c(0,0,0,0,0), v2=c(0,0,1,1,1), ms=c(0,0,0,0,0), yv=c(0,0,1,0,1))

vars <- c("ac", "fv", "vs", "v2", "ms", "yv")
a <- apply(data.frame(t(combn(vars, 5))), 1, paste, collapse="+")
```

The model should look like this, with the dependent variable `death` and the independent variables of each element of `a`:

```
glm(death ~ a, data=de.dat, family="binomial")
```

In order to get the best model, I then need to extract the BIC of every model and then to be able to identify which BIC belongs to which model. Thank in advance.

Comment: An alternative approach for model selection for a logistic regression would be to use L1 regularization.  This will shrink the coefficients of unimportant covariates to 0.  A tutorial can be found here http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will have a look at it over the weekend. I guess my initial try is a bit naive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should help you.
Here is your data:

```
de.dat <- data.frame(death=c(0,0,0,1,0), ac=c(1, 2, 2, 3, 2), fv=c(1,0,0,0,1), vs=c(0,0,0,0,0), v2=c(0,0,1,1,1), ms=c(0,0,0,0,0), yv=c(0,0,1,0,1))
vars <- c("ac", "fv", "vs", "v2", "ms", "yv")
```

You should create character vector with whole formula inside (not only the right part):

```
a <- apply(cbind(paste(names(de.dat)[1],"~"),data.frame(t(combn(vars, 5)))), 1, paste, collapse="+")
```

Then, using `lapply` function you can create a list, which consists of all your 6 models:

```
models <- lapply(a,FUN = function(X) glm(X, data=de.dat, family="binomial"))
```